# Can't connect to a wireless network from Ubuntu but I can from Windows

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

**Short explanation:**

The wireless connection (which is an extended signal from another one) that I used to use in my ubuntu computers no longer works, whereas it works perfectly from my Windows computers. I can connect through wired cable or to the original network without problems, so I can discard problems in my hardware and I am assuming the problem may be caused by network's configuration. (this is why I discarded older posts that suggest to disable N protocol or or simply don't work [after 15.10 changed network interface names](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes))

**Long explanation:**

I have several devices connected to a wireless network through a [wifi extender](http://netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN2000RPT.aspx), some of which are using kubuntu 16.04 (a laptop and a computer, which have different hardware settings) and others windows 10. This setting has been working fine for months till yesterday, when none of the devices could connect to the extended wireless network.

Since rebooting the extender didn't fix the problem I reset it to factory default and configured it again. This fixed the problems on my Windows' devices but not on my Ubuntu ones. I am afraid this has to be a problem with that particular network's configuration, since I have performed this tasks:

- I can connect to the original wireless network (even with my ubuntu laptops) if I move to another room within the router's range.
- I can connect perfectly to the Internet using a wired connection directly to the wifi extender -> this might discard problems with its hardware and might confirm that the bridge between the router and the extender works fine.
- I made sure that there is no configuration preventing certain devices to connect to the network, since Access Control is not enabled on my wifi extender nor in my router.
- I removed the network from my Network configuration manager and I re-added it.
- I removed the files stored on `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`
   regarding to that particular wireless network.
- I can connect to other networks with the same hardware -> this might discard problems related to my hardware configuration
- When I log in into windows using dualboot I can log in to the network -> this might discard hardware issues.

I have also read other questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16777/connecting-to-a-wireless-network), but I don't like them, since as far as I can understand, they disable N protocol, which additionally I don't believe is my problem.

Comment: Just a thought, but beliefs are *not* facts.  If you were to try a solution even though you don't believe it will help you could say factually that it doesn't resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thes problem has suddenly solved after some upgrades using a wired connection. I'm afraid there might be due to a problem with certain packages, as it was suddenly solved from my two computers on the same day and since I could connect to the same wifi from an older kubuntu version without problems.